# Return new date after adding the number to the today's date in node js

Tags: node.js

I have a logical question may be it sound simple but I am facing problem while solving this. Situation is I have a number of days that is expire days now by using that number I have to create a expire date, let me give you one example.

```
if today's date is 25-07-2020 and no.of expire days is 10 then expire date should be 04-08-2020
```

I want to this to implement in `node js`, right now I am getting today's date using Date method.

```
const today = new Date().toISOString().replace(/\T.+/, '')
```

This returns today's date but now I am confused how can I get my expire date after adding no.of days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `setDate` here

```
   var currentDate = new Date();
   currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate() + 10);
   console.log(currentDate) //this will have the new date
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a function:

```
function addDays(date, days) {
  const copy = new Date(Number(date))
  copy.setDate(date.getDate() + days)
  return copy
}

const date = new Date();
const newDate = addDays(date, 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

So, you can't add 10 days by simple manipulation of the Date as a string, since you'd need to account for all sorts of edge cases (change of month, change of year, time-zone changes).

There are lots of good libraries out there that can help you, like [date-fns](https://date-fns.org/v2.2.1) or [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/).

However, if you want to do this without a library, it's quite straightforward:

```
const now = +new Date(); // Gets the date as ms since epoch
const expiry = new Date(now + (10 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)); Adds 10 days worth of ms
```